# Store user UUID inside of Android Keychain to persist after app update/uninstall

Tags: android

Hi I have an Android module which is bundled with other apps. The module generates a UUID which needs to persist on the device, even if the user uninstalls the app. Is it possible to store this UUID String into the Keychain/keystore?

thanks.

Comment: If it survived an uninstall, that would be a bug in Android. Everything private to an app should be removed upon uninstallation.

Comment: So is the only alternative to write this UUID to a file in the external storage? I wanted to avoid that as well.

Comment: "So is the only alternative to write this UUID to a file in the external storage?" -- that will not work, insofar as the user can delete that at any time.

Answer (score 0):

If your users authenticate themselves on your server (for example, to use your API), you can store UUID generated by a device as a part of users data, and push it back to app shared prefs when a user successfully authenticates himself from a new device.

Comment: The module has no authentication.  We identify the user in the API with the UUID, so if there UUID changes post install/uninstall/reinstall, then it looks like a new user.

Comment: in this situation your problem seems to have no solution - in case on legal or illegal UUID change you will see a "new user" ;-(